# Why is the edge of a closed achronal set equal to the edge of its future Cauchy horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality, topology

This question is related to Proposition 6.5.2 of Hawking & Ellis. It states that

$$\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))=\text{edge}(\mathscr S),$$

for a closed achronal set $\mathscr S$.

Of course, Hawking & Ellis gave a proof. But I could not understand it. Instead, I try to prove it using different methods.

It is easy to show that

$$\text{edge}(\mathscr S)\subset\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S)).$$

Let me give a proof briefly. Consider $q\in\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$. Then, by definition, $q\in\mathscr S\Rightarrow q\in {D^+(\mathscr S)}$. In fact, $q\in\tilde D^+(\mathscr S)=\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}$ according to Proposition 6.5.1. And, at the same time, $q\notin I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))$. Therefore, $q\in H^+(\mathscr S)$. Suppose $q\notin \text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))$. Then, there is a neighborhood $\mathscr U$ of $q$ such that every timelike curve from $I^+(q,\mathscr U)$ to $I^-(q,\mathscr U)$ intersects $H^+(\mathscr S)$, then every such curve can be extended to the past and intersects $\mathscr S$, by the definition of $H^+(\mathscr S)$. Therefore, $q\notin\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$. A contradiction. Therefore, $q\in\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))$, and $\text{edge}(\mathscr S)\subset\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))$.

However, I cannot prove

$$\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))\subset\text{edge}(\mathscr S).$$

What I can get is if $q\in\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))$, $q\in H^+(\mathscr S)$. I cannot show $q\in\mathscr S$, let alone $q\in\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

(In the following, I gave my thoughts about how to prove the proposition. I am not sure if it is correct. Obviously, I did not try to make the following discussion rigorous.)

---

Let me show if one can show $q\in\mathscr S$, then $q\in\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$ based on what is given.

Suppose $q\notin \text{edge}(\mathscr S)$.
Then, there is an open set $\mathscr Q$ of $q$ such that all timelike curve connecting points in $I^+(q,\mathscr Q)$ and $I^-(q,\mathscr Q)$ intersect $\mathscr S$.
Therefore, any point $r\in I^+(q,\mathscr Q)$ is also a point in $\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}$. Since $q\in I^-(r)$, then $q\in I^-(\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)})=I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))$, but this is in contradiction with $q\in H^+(\mathscr S)=\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}-I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))$.
So $q\in\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$, that is, $\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))\subset\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$. Then, one shows $\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))=\text{edge}(\mathscr S)$.

But how can we prove $q\in\mathscr S$ in the first place?

Let me give a tentative proof. The following would be fairly informal. In some places, I might give a handwaving proof, because I am not sure if my proof is correct or not.

First, consider a point $q\in\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))$.
$\Rightarrow q\in\overline{H^+(\mathscr S)}$. So any open set $\mathscr U$ containing $q$ intersects $H^+(\mathscr S)=\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}-I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))\Rightarrow\mathscr U\cap\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}\ne\emptyset$.
$\Rightarrow q\in\overline{\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}}=\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}$.

Since $\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}\cap I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))\ne\emptyset$, it is possible that $q\in I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))$.
Then, suppose $q\in I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))\cap\overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}$. Then, there is a point $x\in D^+(\mathscr S)$ which is in $I^+(q)$. On the one hand, since $x\in D^+(\mathscr S)$, every past-inextendible timelike curve from $x$ intersects $\mathscr S$.
On the other hand, $q\in I^-(x)$, and thus, $I^-(x)\cap H^+(\mathscr S)\ne\emptyset$. So $x$ is in $I^+[H^+(\mathscr S)]$, which means that there exists a past inextendible timelike curve from $x$ that never intersects $\mathscr S$.
So one finds a contradiction. Therefore, $q\notin I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))$, but $q\in \overline{D^+(\mathscr S)}$, which implies that $q\in H^+(\mathscr S)$. Of course, $q\in\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))$.

Now, there are two possibilities: either $q\in\mathscr S$, or $q\in H^+(\mathscr S)-\mathscr S$.

Consider $q\in H^+(\mathscr S)-\mathscr S$. One knows that $q\in I^+(\mathscr S)$. Since $\mathscr S$ is closed, there is an open neighborhood $\mathscr W$ of $q$ such that $\mathscr W\subset I^+(\mathscr S)$.
One knows that $I^-(q,\mathscr W)\subset\tilde D^+(\mathscr S)$, otherwise, there is a past inextendible timelike curve from $q$ that does not intersect $\mathscr S$.
In fact, $\overline{I^-(q,\mathscr W)}\subset\tilde D^+(\mathscr S)$.
Let the set $A=\{q|q\in\text{edge}(H^+(\mathscr S))-\mathscr S\}$. $A$ might contain several disconnected components. Let us just consider one such component $A_1$, and assume $A_1$ is infinite and "continuous".
We do not consider "discontinuous" set, as in that case, the points $q$'s are isolated from each other and from the rest part of $H^+(\mathscr S)$.
Like $q$, it is possible to find a neighborhood $\mathscr W_1$ of $A_1$, such that $\mathscr W_1\subset I^+(\mathscr S)$.
And one knows that $\overline{I^-(A_1,\mathscr W_1)}\subset\tilde D^+(\mathscr S)$. In fact, $\mathcal H=\overline{I^-(A_1,\mathscr W_1)}-I^-(D^+(\mathscr S))\subset H^+(\mathscr S)$.
That is, intuitively, if one assumes such a set $A$ exists, the future Cauchy horizon can be "extended", so $q$ is not the edge of $H^+(\mathscr S)$.
So $q$ has to be in $\mathscr S$.